# Change the default dashes in Django Createview from

Tags: django

Is there a way to change the default dashes in Django CreateView based form to a needed text, e.g. 'Select a Product' in my case?

Code of my [view](https://gist.github.com/Konstantin555/84a044d7f11198c6b2b24d6c040fe715)

[form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfhoA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please next time, paste your code into StackOverflow, not github. 
To achieve what you want, do as follow:

```
def get_form(self):
    form = super(CreateView, self).get_form()
    form.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user, tracking_on=True)
    form.fields['product'].empty_label = "Select a product"
    ...
    return form
```

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot.